# Como resolver is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: html, angular

Tenho um botão em uma tabela que esta com o seguinte código

> `<td> <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" onclick="addCart()"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Adicionar ao Carrinho </button> </td>`

Mas ele fica retornando o erro "Uncaught ReferenceError: addCart is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"
E essa função existe no código, não sei qual pode ser esse problema.

Comment: Mas está utilizando **Angular**???

Comment: Não seria `ng-click`?? Mas coloque a assinatura da função assim como o elemento `<script>` a qual ela está inserida.

Comment: Tentei ng-click tbm sem sucesso

Answer (score 1):

Se você está usando o Angular você deve dar a instrução do click no seu botão da seguinte forma:

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="addCart()">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Adicionar ao Carrinho
    </button>
</td>
```

E no arquivo TypeScript do seu componente você deve criar a função `addCart()`

Com isso deve funcionar. Se ainda estiver dando erro, coloque o código completo do template e do componente se for possível.

Comment: Estou usando o angular, só que na minha tabela estou usando a footable, e por algum motivo o (click)="addCart()" nao funciona, ai estava procurando outros meio de fazer um botão funcionar rs

Comment: Tem como adicionar o código TypeScript e do template pra ter uma ideia melhor e conseguir te ajudar?

Answer (score -2):

"function addCart(){
}"
é so meter isso num javascript que para de dar esse erro 0.0
Se o erro continuar é porque tens alguma ligação mal, talvez ao ficheiro js